# Why do I get an error when trying to run this code on Metabase?

Tags: metabase

```
SELECT((SELECT count(*) 
FROM `bookings`
WHERE `bookings`.`status` = 'collect_payment'
AND {{created_at}}))
/
((SELECT count(*) 
FROM `bookings`
AND {{created_at}})
 ;
```

I am trying to divided two values by dividing two select statement but it does not work

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? You query is syntactically wrong. You have missed a brace in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated working query:

```
SELECT((SELECT count(*) 
FROM `bookings`
WHERE `bookings`.`status` = 'collect_payment'
AND {{created_at}}))
/
((SELECT count(*) 
FROM `bookings`
AND {{created_at}}))
```

Did you map / configure `{{created_at}}` ?
If not mapped already, map it and rerun the query.